# Prepare update command using sed

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, ksh

I have a output file that contains 3 different column data-

```
          ['AARF'],SAMPLE12,2016-01-05 12:00:00-0500
                  ,529OFFST,2015-04-16 08:04:21-0400
          "['EPROSP_IWS', '648099_EPROSP_IWS']",4.NDR-IWS-EPRO,2015-04-16 08:04:21-0400
```

I tried with below sed command-

```
        sed -i "s/\(\"*\[[^]]*\]\"*\)\(.*\)/{\1:\"\"}\2/" tempFile
        sed "s/' *, *'/' '/g;s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/update table set cross_refs = \1 where id = \2 and effective_date = \3/;s/' '/','/g" tempFile > updatestmt.cql
        sed -i "s/$/';/" updatestmt.cql
```

My Expected o/p-

```
       update table set cross_refs ={'AARF':''}  where id = 'SAMPLE12' and effective_date = '2016-01-05 12:00:00-0500';
       update table set cross_refs = {'':''}  where id = '529OFFST' and effective_date = '22016-01-05 12:00:00-0500';
       update table set cross_refs = {'EPROSP_IWS':'','648099_EPROSP_IWS':''} where id = '4.NDR-IWS-EPRO' and effective_date = '2015-04-16 08:04:21-0400';
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: So you really want the second line of output to be invalid SQL?

Comment: I am trying to copy old column data to new column in cassandra. If you see the 2nd line cross_refs = empty where id = .. So value is empty. So its not an invalid statement.

Comment: Indeed its a wrong statement. thank you for noticing that.. just updating my post

Comment: Can you please help me in to achieving that

Comment: Difficult.  Your input is irregular (sometimes the bracketed section is a quoted string, sometimes not; number of fields per input line varies; single delimiter used to separate several layers of fields).

Comment: I would do this manually in Vim and create macros to assist.  I could reuse the macros for the next time, but it looks like the automation via Perl et. al. would take more time than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do it in `awk`:

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    date=$NF
    id=$(NF-1)
    sub(/^ */, "", $1)
    sub(/"?\[/, "", $1)
    sub(/\]"?/, "", $(NF-2))
    ref = $1
    for (i=2; i < NF-1; i++) {
        ref = ref ":''," $(i)
    }
    if (!ref) { ref = "''" }
    print "update table set cross_refs={" ref ":''} where id='" id "' and effective_date = '" date "';\
"
}
```